# How to pass event and other arguments inside an arrow function in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events, dom-events, arrow-functions

I am a beginner in React and was held up with an issue:

This was my code inside the render function

```
let contnt = null;
        if(this.state.showPersons)
        {
          contnt = (
            <div >
              {this.state.persons.map((ppl,index)=>{
                return <Person name={ppl.name} 
                                age={ppl.age} 
                                changed={this.nameChange}  // THE FOCUS POINT
                                click={()=>this.deletePerson(index)}
                                key={index}></Person>
              }) }
            </div>

          )
        }
```

The code above works fine the function ***nameChange*** reads event as well, without explicitly sending it as argument.

But I wanted to send index to my ***nameChange*** function as well, but if I define ***changed*** as :

```
changed={()=>this.nameChange(event, index)}
```

It gives error saying event not found...

***How do I send event along with arguments to an arrow function definition inside render function?***

I know this might seem to be a very basic question, but beginners who tend to start off haphazardly often face simple basic issues like this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was following a tutorial there after and found it, so thought it was worth sharing..

And event can be sent in the first parenthesis of the arrow function like this:

```
changed={(event)=>this.nameChange(event, index)}
```

and then event as well as index can be read in the nameChange function.